# Rails - Couldn't find User with id=edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Rails 3 and Devise for authentication. When I try to update my `current_user`, an exception is thrown stating:

```
Couldn't find User with id=edit
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:49:in `update'
```

Here is `update` and `edit` in UsersController:

```
#UsersController.rb
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

And here is `/views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path, :class => 'brand' %>
<ul class="nav">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li>
    <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete') %>
    </li>
  <% else %>
    <li>
    <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  <li>
  <%= link_to('About', help_about_path) %>
  </li>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li>
    <%= link_to('Edit Account', edit_user_path(current_user)) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  <% if user_signed_in? and current_user.role == "gen_admin" || current_user.role == "teacher" %>
    <li>
    <%= link_to('View Students', users_path ) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  <% if user_signed_in? and current_user.role == "gen_admin" || current_user.role == "teacher" %>
    <li>
    <%= link_to('New User', new_user_path ) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
     <li>
     <%= link_to('Student Data', data_path) %>
     </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Finally, here is `/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb`:

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => edit_user_registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :teacher %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :teacher %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
    <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <div><%= f.label :new_password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

Why is the user id=edit? Here is my hash, if that helps:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"7g1WsNCVuNY/5ZTeBUdv97tbdAPacvvDAzBSMGCcuNY=",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"email@admin.com",
 "teacher"=>"Demont",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Update",
 "id"=>"edit",
 "format"=>"user"}
```

Comment: may you post the code of your edit action?

Comment: I added the `edit` action. It is very late here so I will try to solve this in the morning using everyones responses here and mark the answer that worked best for me. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
@user = current_user
```

Something looks to be wrong with your route or edit form. Try using the form like in their wiki page...
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

But the above code should get around this

Comment: You are probably right, there may be a larger issue in my routes. But for now using `current_user` instead of `params[:id]` works for me. Thanks to everyone else, I am sure those are valid answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you I've got conflict in your routes when added `UsersController`.

There is [devise's wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface) explaining that.

Default devise's route for edit user is `/users/edit` but in your controller path for update action is `/users/:id`. What's why you've got "edit" instead of `user_id`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<%= form_for(@resource, :as => resource_name, :url => edit_user_registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
```

to your form view and

```
@resource = User.find(params[:id])
```

in your edit action.